# Trying to get property of non-object / Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am aware that this question has been asked many times but the solutions doesn't seem to be working for me.

I am writing a simple blog and I wanted to make an archive section, but I got stuck. This is a piece of code that I have and that is troublesome:

```
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $year = $_GET['year'];

            $from = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime("$year-$month"));
            $to = date('Y-m-31 23:59:59', strtotime("$year-$month"));

            echo $from;
            echo $to;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date >= ".$from." AND date <= ".$to." ORDER BY date DESC";
            $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
            var_dump($stmt);

            if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
```

And this piece of code is giving me the following error in the if statement (Trying to get property of non-object). The var_dump() returns bool(false). So it seems that the query is a problem, but as far as I'm concerned it is okay. I checked it and there is not typos and all names are correct too.

I also tried to do it like this:

```
            $month = $_GET['month'];
            $year = $_GET['year'];

            $from = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime("$year-$month"));
            $to = date('Y-m-31 23:59:59', strtotime("$year-$month"));

            echo $from;
            echo $to;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date >= ".$from." AND date <= ".$to." ORDER BY date DESC";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            var_dump($stmt);
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
            $stmt->execute();
```

But it gives me a different error (Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean) so again it seems that the query is a problem. I don't really know how to deal with this. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

```
                $month = $_GET['month'];
            $year = $_GET['year'];

            //set from and to dates
            $from = date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', strtotime("$year-$month"));
            $to = date('Y-m-31 23:59:59', strtotime("$year-$month"));

            echo $from;
            echo $to;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ? ORDER BY date DESC";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            //var_dump($stmt);
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postId=".$row['id'];
                    $comNumber = $conn->query($query);
                    $total = $comNumber->num_rows;


                    echo "<section class='post'>
                                <img class='postImage' src='img/".$row['id'].".png'>
                                <div class='postComment'>
                                    <div class='postCommentBubble'><img src='img/commentBubble.svg'></div>
                                    <div class='postCommentCount'>".$total." comments</div>";

                    echo "<div class='postDate'>".date("d F Y G:i", strtotime($row["date"]))."</div>";

                        if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['privileges']==true){
                            echo "<a class='postDelete' href='delete-post.php?id=".$row["id"]."'><img src='img/garbage.svg'></a>";
                            echo "<a class='postEdit' href='edit-post.php?id=".$row["id"]."'><img src='img/pencil.svg'></a>";
                        }

                        echo "</div>
                                <header class='postTitle'><a href='post.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</a></header>
                                <div class='postIntro'>".$row['intro']."</div>
                                <div class='postLinkContainer'><a class='postLink' href='post.php?id=".$row['id']."'>read more</a></div>
                            </section>
                            ";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a read here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php prepare you get a false if it fails. Hence your error.

The issue is your SQL your need to use `?` in place of variable names and prepare expects the data to bind. I believe you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ? ORDER BY date DESC";
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
```

Comment: True. That is what was wrong and it got rid of the error, but still I don't get the results for some reason. I updated the first post with more code. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @hinvest Sorry I am not sure what output you are getting and what you expected based on the code. Can you run the query and get the results you expect? This is extending the question though. You may want to take the time and look at the sql and PHP now and ask another question later.

Comment: So my problem is that I don't get any results. MySQL doesn't return any rows even though there are rows in a database that match the "date" requirement from the query.

Comment: @hinvest you really need to separate this out. You are getting two separate answers on one SO thread which is counter-productive to some in the future to finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your updated status, fetch_assoc() is not a member of a mysqli statement object.  However, fetch() is and is the member function you are looking for.

You can also use bind_result() to access the data.

So an example would look something like:

```
    $timestamp = time();

    //create select statement
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT column_x, column_y, column_z FROM table_name WHERE date < ?");

    //bind $timestamp to the prepared statement
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $timestamp);
    $stmt->execute();

    //bind each selected column to a variable for iteration
    $stmt->bind_result($column_x, $column_y, $column_z);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $x . " " . $y . " " . $z . "\n";
    }
```

Here is the reference link for the [mysqli_stmt class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php)

edit: I would also like to point out that while a mysli_stmt object does have a num_rows property, it is not the same as the num_rows property on a query result.

Comment: Please see my last comment. While you may be correct (I have not verified anything) there are two answers to two questions in one thread. This is not how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: @nerdlyist don't care.  just tried to help someone.